# Как организовать взаимодействие между клиентами и сервером?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

Написал простой сервер на сокетах. Данные передаются в потоках, а потом работа заканчивается. Но это только выполнение одних действий со стороны сервера. Как сделать так, чтобы клиент САМ выбирал что ему делать. Например вызвать метод для сохранения данных в бд. Подскажите технологии которые упростят это дело. На примете технология RMI. Но думаю, что есть еще стек технологий которые сделают это лучше.

Comment: Вам обязательно нужны сокеты? Например, если вы напишете веб сервер, то сможете принимать разные запросы как разные действия от клиентов.

Comment: @tym32167 нет, сокеты не обязательны. Просто это самый простой пример, во всяком случае мне так показалось, написать сервер. А веб сервер чем отличается?

Comment: я в java не силен, но мне кажется, что с точки зрения разработки сервера и клиента, отладки, тестирования и установки веб сервер вам будет попроще накидать, чем возиться с сокетами.

Comment: @КотовНикита, клиент может посылать текстовые команды на сервер. Сервер слушает клиента и процессит команды.

Comment: @Alexey, разве это правильный подход?

Comment: @КотовНикита может и нет. Какой правильный на ваш взгляд?

Comment: @Alexey, если бы я знал - вопрос бы не задавал) Я только начал изучать серверную разработку, поэтому ищу проверенные пути.

Comment: Тоже пользуюсь методом Алексея. Задачу свою выполняет идеально, что еще нужно :)

Comment: Взаимодействие между двумя программами на `Java` или в роли клиента выступает браузер?

Comment: Для написания backend можешь использовать Spring, в нём уже довольно много реализовано возможностей взаимодействия клиент-сервер через тот же REST. В качестве БД можно как SQL так и например MongoDB. В своё время я так же пробовал на сокетах писать сервер, но потом научился работать со Spring Boot. В ютубе довольно много роликов, посвящённых этой технологии, ну и так же не мало документации. У тебя всё получится!